# Magento Checkout Extension - Move to Next Step in Checkout

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I'm building a Magento extension that runs a few checks before proceeding from the payment -> review section.

I have a pop up that appears, user enters information and it passes a JSON object back saying it's ok to move forward. My question is this:

In Javascript, I need to proceed to the next step in checkout (which is review). I have the following basic code listed below, if pass variable comes back as "pass" then we can move forward. I have it successfully hitting the else statement below:

```
if (isAllowed != 'pass') {

    // Run code to show error message

}
else {

    // Run code to disable lightbox, allow pass to next step

    checkout.gotoSection('review'); // Attempt 1
    checkout.gotoSection(\'checkout-step-review\'); // Attempt 2 (this one worked, but has obvious syntax errors) - Found this online
    accordion.openSection('opc-review'); // Attempt 3

}
```

My issue is that for each line in the else statement (all separate attempts) I used each individually and only 1 of them (attempt 2) brought me to the next page, but has a syntax error. The other two don't do anything. I found attempt 2 online in many different places. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get to this step, looking at the button that Magento uses, I took this code from the onClick function and it worked as needed.

```
payment.save();
```

I moved this in my code replacing everything in the else statement (they were together for example purposes only)